# How did my deleted question get a comment?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I deleted my question pretty quickly after it was posted when I realized I'd posted on Blender SE instead of Python SO. But it still received a comment afterward. Is it really gone?

This is the "share" [link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/874/5334) to the question, but it seems that since it is deleted - nobody can see it, or at least leave comments?

Comment: When you've got enough reputation, you can view deleted posts, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools It seems that moderators are also able to comment on deleted posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was me, and moderators can comment anywhere, anytime.

When a post is deleted it is not removed from the site.

> ### What does deletion mean for a post?
>
> Deleted posts are usually **not** physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted). This means they won't appear in search results or data dumps, and normal users following links to them will see a 404 (not found) page explaining the cause of deletion.
>
> Moderators, and normal users with >=10k reputation, see all deleted posts that they have links to.

Quoted from: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/278094)

So while you did delete it, now that you posted a link to it any user with 2,000 rep (on a beta site like ours) can still read it.

I just added the comment because I thought it would be helpful (nobody can answer a deleted question).

Comment: Aha! OK thank you for the explanation. So a deleted question just gets more and more difficult to "find" (after 60 days for example) unless I keep a personal copy of the link somewhere. And apparently that's what I did without realizing it by adding a link in this question. OK, live and learn. Thanks!